# Is there a version of Elementary based on a kernel that doesn't require a pae-capable CPU?

Tags: system-installation

I want to install Elementary OS on a Compaq nx6110. Using a Luna-based ISO, I get an "unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU" message. Apparently Ubuntu ver 12 has a kernel which doesn't require the pae capability. Is there an early version of Elementary based on Ubuntu ver 12?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a version of elementary OS that can be installed on a non-PAE CPU.